# Proving a probability function is a pdf

Tags: probability, statistics

The exercise is

[image: ![[http://i.imgur.com/vVjqKVe.png]]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89ARa.png)

I managed to get -1, Can anyone confirm the answer? Also in regards to the expectation question, would you do separate integrals of the two functions and then add them together?

Thank you!

Comment: It cannot be right, the mean depends on $\alpha$ and $\beta$. If $\alpha=\beta$ the answer is $0$.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, the -1 that I achieved was for the first part, I was hoping someone could do the calculation to see where I had gone wrong

Comment: You just made a sign error during your integrations. The integrals are both positive.

Comment: They can't be, because the first integral is between $infty$ and 0 therefore it must be negative

Comment: Also is my method for calculating the expectation correct?

Comment: For the mean, doing two integrals is the right way.

Comment: no, both integrals are positive because $e^{ax}$ is always positive for all real $x $

Comment: Also I'm almost certain the answer is -1, can you confirm this please? Thank you!

Comment: The answer is definitely not equal to $-1$.

Comment: No but you have to minus $e^0/ \alpha$

Comment: Doesn't the first integral = $-\beta/ \alpha +\beta$ + second integral =  $-\alpha/ \alpha +\beta$ ?

Comment: $\alpha,\beta>0$ are **positive integers**, everything within the integral is positive

Comment: But what about the negative sign!

Comment: For example  $\int_{-\infty}^0 \frac{\alpha\beta}{\alpha+\beta}e^{\alpha x}\,dx=\frac{\beta}{\alpha+\beta}$.

Comment: Oh my god I'm being a massive bufoon! Super apologies for my retard moment!

Comment: Can anyone answer the expectation so I could double check please?!

Comment: regarding the expectation I would split the integral and then use partial integration - you can easily check your answer with wolfram.alpha for example

Comment: So would you do the integral of the limit $-\infty<x<0$ + $0<x<\infty$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the expectation, we need 
$$\int_{-\infty}^0 x\cdot\frac{\alpha\beta}{\alpha+\beta}e^{\alpha x}\,dx+ \int_0^\infty x\cdot\frac{\alpha\beta}{\alpha+\beta}e^{-\beta x}\,dx.$$

We make a couple of comments about the second integral. In principle we do it  by parts, $u=x$ and $dv$ the rest. But if you are familiar with the fact that the mean of the exponential with parameter $\beta$ is $\frac{1}{\beta}$ you can see that our second integral is a close relative. It has value $\dfrac{\alpha}{\beta(\alpha+\beta)}$.

By symmetry, or by an integration by parts, the first integral has value $-\dfrac{\beta}{\alpha(\alpha+\beta)}$.

Add. When you bring to a common denominator there will be some cancellation.

Comment: Thank you very much, that is exactly what I needed!

Comment: You are welcome. Note that if one has some familiarity/intuition about the exponential, the answers really don't require calculation.